# No StandardScaler class in sklearn.preprocessing

Tags: scikit-learn

I wanted to use the `StandardScaler` class in the preprocessing package http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler but I keep getting an `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StandardScaler'` on scikit-learn 0.13

`preprocessing.__dict__` does not show `StandardScaler`.

I could use the `LabelEncoder` class in the same package.

Answer (score 4):

The `sklearn` package in your python path is probably an old version and not the 0.13 version you installed. Try:

```
python -c "import sklearn; print(sklearn.__file__)"
```

to check whether this the expected sklearn install location or not.

To resolve duplicate installation problem I found it useful to run:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
```

several times until I get an error message telling explicitly that scikit-learn is not installed on the system. Then:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

once to install the latest stable release (i.e. 0.13.1 at the time of writing).

Comment: `print sklearn.__file__` outputs /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.13_git-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/sklearn/__init__.pyc

Comment: Weird, I just tried with the binary release of sklearn 0.13 that ships with anaconda CE and I don't get the issue:

>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__file__
'/Users/ogrisel/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.pyc'
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.13'
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
>>> StandardScaler()
StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)